# Expected resource of type integer with an image

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-drawable

I am working with Android Studio and Kotlin.

I am trying to use different images in my project (in drawable):

But when I am trying to use one in the DataSource file, it happens an error:

```
package com.example.affirmations.data

import com.example.affirmations.R
import com.example.affirmations.model.Affirmation


class DataSource {

    fun loadAffirmations():List<Affirmation>{
        return listOf<Affirmation>(
            Affirmation(R.string.affirmation1, R.drawable.image1),
//            Affirmation(string.affirmation2, R.drawable.image2),
//            Affirmation(string.affirmation3, R.drawable.image3),
//            Affirmation(string.affirmation4),
//            Affirmation(string.affirmation5),
//            Affirmation(string.affirmation6),
//            Affirmation(string.affirmation7),
//            Affirmation(string.affirmation8),
//            Affirmation(string.affirmation9),
//            Affirmation(string.affirmation10)
        )

    }
}
```

[image]

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wherever you define `Affirmation` (you can hold Ctrl or whatever and click it to go there) it's expecting an Integer resource for the second parameter - it's probably annotated with [`@IntegerRes`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/annotation/IntegerRes) instead of [`@DrawableRes`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/annotation/DrawableRes)

Comment: Thank you, but I have another problem now